# ContentType in header in multipart and in Dio in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, content-type, multipart

I have been trying to upload image and data to server and used both form `http-multipart` and `Dio` but server responding `502` error. As per my research it is happening because i'm providing `Content-Type` in header. I tried so many ways but  still not working.

Dio Code

```
Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
    headers.putIfAbsent("Authorization", () =>token);
    headers.putIfAbsent("Content-Type", () => "multipart/form-data");

    try {
      Dio dio = Dio();
      dio.options.contentType = Headers.formUrlEncodedContentType;
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
        "file": await MultipartFile.fromFile(_image.path,
            filename: "tshirt_view_kovi.jpg"),
        'name': fields.companyName,
        'type': type,
        'contactId': fields.companyPhone,
        'taxId': fields.taxId,
        'lat': "90",
        'long': "180",
        'address': fields.companyAddress,
        'title': fields.representativeTitle,
        'representative': fields.representativeName,
        'state': fields.state,
        'city': fields.city,
        'zip': fields.zip,
      });
      Response response = await dio.post(
          "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/v1/account/business/create",
          data: formData,
          options: Options(headers: headers));
      Log.e("Response",response);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
```

`http-multipart` code

```
Map<String, String> headers = new Map<String, String>();
    headers.putIfAbsent("Authorization", () => token);
    headers.putIfAbsent("Content-Type", () => "multipart/form-data");
    Map<String, String> body = {
      'name': fields.companyName,
      'type': type,
      'contactId': fields.companyPhone,
      'taxId': fields.taxId,
      'lat': "90",
      'long': "180",
      'address': fields.companyAddress,
      'title': fields.representativeTitle,
      'representative': fields.representativeName,
      'state': fields.state,
      'city': fields.city,
      'zip': fields.zip,
    };


    Log.e("URL", url);
    Log.e("URL", body);
    Log.e("TOken", token);

    var uri = Uri.parse(
        "https://xxxxxxxxx.com/v1/account/business/create");
    var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);

    if (_image != null) {
      //var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(_image.openRead()));
      //var length = await _image.length();
      //var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('imageCover', stream, length, filename: _image.path);
      //request.files.add(multipartFile);

      request.files.add(
          http.MultipartFile(
              'imageCover',
              File(_image.path).readAsBytes().asStream(),
              File(_image.path).lengthSync(),
              filename: _image.path
                  .split("/")
                  .last
          )
      );
    }

    if (logoimage != null) {
      // var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(logoimage.openRead()));
      // var length = await logoimage.length();
      // var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('imageLogo', stream, length, filename: logoimage.path);
      // request.files.add(multipartFile);
      
      request.files.add(
          http.MultipartFile(
              'imageLogo',
              File(_image.path).readAsBytes().asStream(),
              File(_image.path).lengthSync(),
              filename: _image.path
                  .split("/").last
          )
      );
    }

    request.fields.addAll(body);
    request.headers['Authorization'] = token;
    request.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    request.send().then((response) {
      print(response.statusCode);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

Remove your "Content-Type", () => "multipart/form-data" in headers options when you post something with MultipartFile
Make sure your header is using Authorization only.